# A GFCI outlet controlled by a light switch

Tags: wiring, gfci, garbage-disposal

I'm installing a disposal and am wondering how I can control the GFCI that the disposal is plugged into with a switch. I want the switch to control the GFCI outlet to protect the disposal. Thank you.

Comment: You should proof read your question. It doesn't make sense. But if you want to know how to control a GFCI from a light switch, you just wire it like you typically wire a light. Except that instead of it being your power, a switch and a light. You pretend the GFCI is the light. And wire it like that.

Comment: Watch that the gfci you buy is in an energized state when power is switched to it. (Some need to be reset after power goes off.)

Answer (score 1):

If this is a new outlet run take all 3 wires to the switch box the white wire nutted together white to white. The ground you will want to pig tail a ~6" piece to the switch green screw. The black is put on the switch (I usually put the hot on top) and feed the outlet on bottom. Just an FYI Garbage disposals are notorious for eating GFCI's so it may be a good idea to have a spare (just be aware that this can happen).

Comment: Good to stress that white and green must run continuously from appliance thru GFCI thru the switch, or else of course the GFCI will trip instantly.